# Metropolis-Hastings with non-centered Proposal

Tags: markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I am trying to draw samples from the Laplace distribution $\pi^* = \text{exp}(-|\theta|)$, using Metropolis Hastings algorithm with a noncentered proposal, meaning that regular Metropolis wont work.. Now I know for a fact this is not converging, but I am really clueless as to why.

I am trying to sample it using python code, so I will use it to demonstrate my approach.

```
def log_target(x):
    return -np.abs(x)

def eval_log_q(xp, x):
    return scipy.stats.norm.logpdf(xp, x, 1) + scipy.stats.norm.logpdf(xp, x+1, 1)

def sample_q(x):
    return x + npr.normal(0, 1) + npr.normal(1, 1)
```

where the samples are checked for acceptance as follows:

```
x_prop = sample_q(x)
a = np.minimum(1, np.exp(log_target(x_prop) + eval_log_q(x, x_prop) - log_target(x) - eval_log_q(x_prop, x)))

u = npr.rand()
if a > u:
    #accept
```

I know that the chain would converge if I changed the proposal to a centered symmetric one, and thus make it ordinary metropolis sampler. But I feel that this should work as well, since this chain should be irreducible and aperiodic, thus being ergodic. Where am I wrong with this one?

Thank you!

Comment: Just so I understand: is your proposal to set $x' = x + \xi_1 + \xi_2$, where $\xi_1 \sim N(0, 1)$, $\xi_2 \sim N(1, 1)$?

Comment: @πr8 That is correct, yes !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed value need be simulated from a mixture of Normals, not as a sum of Normals. Here is an R version of the corrected code that works as a charm:

```
log_target<-function(x) return(-abs(x))

eval_log_q<-function(xp, x)
   return(log(dnorm(xp, x, 1) + dnorm(xp, x+1, 1)))

sample_q<-function(x) return(x + (runif(1)<.5)+rnorm(1))

x=rep(rnorm(1),1e5)
for(t in 2:1e5){
  x[t]=sample_q(x[t-1])
  if(log(runif(1))>log_target(x[t])-log_target(x[t-1])-
     eval_log_q(x[t],x[t-1])+eval_log_q(x[t-1],x[t])) 
       x[t]=x[t-1]}

hist(x,prob=TRUE,nclass=345)
curve(.5*exp(-abs(x)),add=TRUE,col="tomato")
```

[image]

The Python code posted by the OP is

1. using a Normal mixture as proposal density and in the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance probability
2. simulating a sum of Normal variates instead as proposed value
3. using **the sum of the logarithms** of the Normal densities instead of **the logarithm of the sum** of the Normal densities *(if the proposal is truly a mixture of two Normals, see 1. and 2. above)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Tried to follow your code and my own, with [poor results.](https://imgur.com/a/pi21o3a) However the code works just fine with R as you did, but Im not sure why it wont work with Python.

Comment: Ah, the sum of logarithms was indeed wrong, noticed it only now. If I wanted to keep the proposal simulation as sum of Normal variates, and thus use sum of normal ass proposal density, the code for ```eval_log_q``` would be ```return log(dnorm(xp, x+1, sqrt(2)))``` right? As the density of sum of normal variates should be $X + Y \sim N(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sqrt{\sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2}) $ If im correct?

Comment: Or is it even possible to use sum of Normal variates as the proposal density at all?

Comment: In R code, if my sample_q function is ```sample_q<-function(x) return(x + rnorm(n=1, mean=0, var=1) +rnorm(n=1, mean=1, var=1))
```, would the corresponding eval_loq_q function be ```eval_log_q<-function(xp, x)
   return(log(dnorm(xp, x+1, 1)))```? If not, what would the corresponding eval_log_q function be? And Im still confused as to what markov chain property does my Original Python code break to prevent converging in general.

Comment: The errors are unconnected with Markovian properties and they are listed in my answer. This is basic probability theory: the density of a sum of variates IS NOT the sum of the densities.